# Многопоточное программирование c#

Tags: c#, многопоточность

задача такая:
запускается поток в консоли он ждет ввода данных от пользователя. Как пользователь вводит данные поток закрывается.
Одновременно второй поток работает в фоне и если пользователь не вводит никаких данных в течении минуты закрывает первый поток.
Можете представить решение программы.

Comment: конечно же нет.

Comment: А сами пробовали что-то делать в этом направлении? Тут могут помочь, но готовое решение вам вряд ли выложат.

Comment: В чем заключается вопрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ради интереса написал так

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Timers;
using Timer = System.Timers.Timer;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        private static string UserText;
        private static Thread FirstThread;
        private static Thread SecondThread;
        private static Timer Timer;

        static void Main()
        {
            FirstThread = new Thread(GetText);
            SecondThread = new Thread(SessionTimer);

            FirstThread.Start();
            SecondThread.Start();
        }

        private static void GetText()
        {
            UserText = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine($"Hello my dear, {UserText}");
            Console.Read();
        }

        private static void SessionTimer()
        {
            Timer = new Timer();
            Timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
            Timer.Interval = 60000;
            Timer.Enabled = true;
        }

        private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!FirstThread.IsAlive && !SecondThread.IsAlive)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Все потоки закрыты!");
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserText))
            {
                return;
            }

            if (FirstThread.ThreadState == ThreadState.AbortRequested)
            {
                return;
            }

            FirstThread.Abort();
            Timer.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Поток 2 закрыл поток 1");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Код из 2006 года. Вы к нам на машине времени...? Того?

Answer (score 1):

Есть замечательный метод Task.WaitAny, которому можно задать timeout:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var readingTask = new Task(() =>
        {
            var data = Console.ReadLine();
        });
        Task.WaitAny(
            new[]
            {
                readingTask
            }, 
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
    }
}
```